# Excitation and acceleration of charges is the only way to produce EM radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

In lasers electrons are excited, in free-electron lasers electrons are periodically accelerated as well as in radio antennas. Radiation is produced when deflected in a magnetic field. Thermal excitation of subatomic particles produces EM radiation. Etc.

Can EM radiation be produced by anything other than the excitation and acceleration of charges?

Note: The question [Is accelerating charges only way to produce EM radiation? What about gamma from nucleus?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286856/is-accelerating-charges-only-way-to-produce-em-radiation-what-about-gamma-from) poses only the acceleration of electrons against that of the nucleus. I want to know if the enumeration of acceleration and excitation are the only causes of EM radiation.

Comment: Atomic, molecular, lattice,,,, transitions. ... means black body radiation

Comment: @annav Phonic excitation and so on can also be added. Think it through. How do all these radiations come about in detail? Will it work without the charges in the atom, molecule, ...?

Comment: Black holes radiate photons with no charged particles involved.

Comment: @Ghoster That is the macroscopic view. In detail it is the thermic wiggling of the charges. What you see is resonant frequencies of a cavity which you can apply for a wide range of EM radiation. What I see are charges wich are excited by EM radiation, and dissipating this energy partly giving back radiation to latice, to phonons and so on and radiating with lower frequency. Than more energy is added, than more the blackbody radiation changes.

Comment: I think it can be shown that black holes would radiate photons even if no charged fields exist in Nature. You can also, in principle, collide intense gravitational waves and create photons, again with no charges involved… just direct photon-graviton couplings.

Comment: It was not until five years after Planck made his heuristic assumption of abstract elements of energy or of action that Albert Einstein conceived of really existing quanta of light in 1905 as a revolutionary explanation of black-body radiation, of photoluminescence, of the photoelectric effect, and of the ionization of gases by ultraviolet light. … Contrary to Planck's beliefs of the time, Einstein proposed a model and formula whereby light was emitted, absorbed, and propagated in free space in energy quanta localized in points of space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law

Comment: @HolgerFiedler  You are putting the cart before the horse. The whole point of the standard model of particle physics is to build up an accurate model for quantum states and to be the basis of the classical theories in a continuous and energy momentum angular momentum and charge conservation manner.So, atoms exist because charge exists and it is postulated to exist in the standard model. That the complicated probabilistic calculation of QM will lead to the simpler phenomenon of radiating charges  is the reason that the standard model is mainstream physics.